# Trying to run Apache Apex's Yahoo Finance example on YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-apex

I've downloaded Apache Apex 3.5.0 along with Malhar 3.5.0.

I've successfully started the apex client and submitted the Yahoo Finance demo example to our YARN cluster (running CDH 5.10). The cluster is running and configured properly (many Spark and MR jobs are running on it).

I see the application I submitted as `RUNNING` in YARN as well as in the Apex cli. However when I try to connect to the Application Master I get a 404.

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /: controller for default not found
```

I also tried directly to connect to the `appMasterTrackingUrl` reported by `get-app-info` command, and I get the same error.

I tried a couple of apex examples, and I always get the same error.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is somewhat expected. Add "/ws/v2/stram/info" to the URL path

Comment: I was expecting some UI like other Application Manager. I wonder why there is not a default redirect to a page with documentation or so.

Comment: Apache Apex applications provide only REST API that is currently documented in the source code only AFAIK. The UI similar to other Application Managers is provided by [Datatorrent RTS](https://www.datatorrent.com/download/).

Comment: Not sure if it would worth a new question, but how can I see the output of a console output operator when using Yarn ?

Comment: Yes, it worth a new question. You may also post questions to user@apex.apache.org.

Comment: I finally found where it is writing. the output is in hdfs under /tmp/fileOutput

Answer (score 2):

When you connect to the App Master you need to provide the complete URL for a REST API to invoke. There is nothing to show/return for "/" so what you are seeing is expected. What are you trying to do connecting to the App Master?

Comment: I guess I was expecting some kind of UI similar to the one we have when are running spark jobs. Or  some documentation to tell me how to query the API. I was not expecting a stack trace.